# Oracle instant client memory footprint

Tags: oracle, client, native-client

In the link mentioned here --> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html it says there is increased virtual memory footprint when running my applications in conjunction with Instant Client.! Why is that so? If that is the case I would rather install the native Oracle client which takes time to install but still end of the day performance matters right? Why should I prefer instant client when there are memory leaks with it?

Answer (score 1):

You link to a FAQ that says

> The Instant Client libraries occupy a virtual address space that is
>   equal to the size of the files. However, only frequently used error
>   messages from the libraries occupy physical memory. Under most cases,
>   the physical memory load is a few kilobytes despite the larger
>   reserved virtual address space

This isn't saying that there is a memory leak in the Instant Client.  It is saying that using the Instant Client involves adding a few kb of physical memory and a bit more virtual memory to your application's memory footprint.  That's normally not something that would impact performance.  If you are running in an environment where a few kb of space is an issue (for example, you're building an application that is supposed to run 10's of thousands of copies of itself on a single server), then you might be better off with a full client install.  Of course, the full client will undoubtedly load more than a few kb of shared libraries into memory, they just won't count as part of your application's footprint.

Comment: "you're building an application that is supposed to run 10's of thousands of copies of itself on a single server" - can you explain a bit more on that?

Comment: @tesla747 - Not sure what you're asking for an explanation on.  It would be odd but you might decide to build an executable that was going to be deployed to a server and that you were going to spawn 10's of thousands of instances of that executable rather than having the executable spawn multiple threads or deploying a client application to a client machine.  At that point, you might care about things like whether each instance of the executable is storing frequently used error messages in physical memory rather than having a single shared copy in memory.